# Automatically quit emacs after git-commit-commit in git-commit mode

Tags: magit, git

I am using `emacs -nw` as in-place commit message editor for my git. When pressing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> in `git-commit` mode, I want emacs to quit automatically. Currently, `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` is saved, and the buffer is killed. Then I am left with the scratch buffer, so I have to quit emacs manually as an extra step.

My guess would be to either create some macro and bind it to some key, or add some kind of hook to `git-commit-commit`.

Comment: Not knowing more about how you are starting up / shutting down emacs for commits, I am hesitant to post an answer, but the the `git-commit-commit-hook` is run right before the buffer is killed. You could likely add a hook in there that determines whether or not to kill emacs and does so.

Comment: I have added the `magit` tag because `git-commit.el` is now part of magit itself. While it is now maintained inside the magit repository it is still available as a separate package and does not depend on `magit`. I will try to keep it that way for as long as I can, but eventually this library might start depending on features provided by libraries that are part of the `magit` package.

Comment: @JordonBiondo, your comment looks like what I was thinking of. I just didn't find that hook. Looking at the answer below, however, I am happy I did not go that path. I have now found emacsclient to work to my advantage. I previously thought it only added complexity and tried to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-commit.el` assumes that the `emacsclient` is used as `$GIT_EDITOR`. When that is the case then aborting does still save the changes to `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, but `emacsclient` then exits with a non-zero exit status, which instructs `git commit` to not create the commit.

It would probably be possible to make this work with `emacs` too, but I am not sure whether that would be worth the increased complexity. It's always preferable to use the `emacsclient`, most importantly this avoids an unnecessary startup delay.

So my recommendation is that you learn how to setup the emacs server and how to connect to it using `emacsclient`.

Or even to give Magit a try. In Magit a commit is initiated simply by pressing `c c`.

*NOTE 1: Op also opened a related issue [here](https://github.com/magit/git-modes/issues/127), let's discuss there whether a future version of `git-commit` should also support using plain old `emacs` as editor.*

*NOTE 2: When OP asked the question `magit v2.1.0` was not released yet. Now, after the release, `git-commit-mode.el` has been renamed to `git-commit.el` and the command that performs the commit is named `with-editor-finish` (the key binding is still the same : <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>.*